# Laravel 5.2 Select control dynamically loading another select control

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel.

I need to populate one select control based on the previous select option that a user selects.

Here is my blade/html(first select is hard coded for now, but the values are what will come from database)

```
<select id="company_type" name="company_type"class="form-control">
    <option value="2">Dealer</option>
    <option value="3">Customer</option>
    <option value="4">Partner</option>
</select>

<select id="organization_type_id" name="organization_type_id"class="form-control">
     @foreach($belongsto as $org)
     <option>{{ $org }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is my javascript

```
        $('#company_type').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var company_type = e.target.value;

        $.get("{{ url('dashboard/addOrganization') }}?company_type=" + company_type, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#organization_type_id').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index,subCatObj){
                $('#organization_type_id').append('subCatObj.name');
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is my Controller (This code is part of a function call that I making within the controller I would be returning a `view` once I get the data I need)

```
$companyType = '3';// Input::get('comapny_type');
$orgs =  Organization::where('organization_type_id','=',$companyType)->get();
return $orgs;
```

In my controller, I have hard coded an option that I expect to get from `Input::get('company_type')` However, the Input call returns null.

The parameters are not showing up in my URL so I am assuming that is the reason it is not working. However, I am not sure how to append `?company_type=3` to the URL, if that is how its supposed to be.

Comment: can you check what does `return Input::get('company_type');` returns on the controller?

Comment: When you say *based on a previous select option* are you implying you want this done dynamically on the page? That's a job for javascript if so

Comment: the Input call returns null.

Comment: "That's a job for javascript if so"  does not really tell me anything that I already don't know.  I know that.  There is some type of ajax request going on behind the scenes because this is Laravel.  As I stated above, I hard coded `$companyType = Input::get('comapny_type');` to `$companyType = '3';`  and it WORKS!   So, `Input::get('comapny_type');`  IS NOT working as I would expect it to.  As  I also stated, I think its because `?company_type=3` is not being appended to the URL.

Comment: Try to separate the blade part of the url in another var. Like `var url="{{ url('dashboard/addOrganization') }}";` then use it `url + "?company_type=" + company_type`